# Assigning the address of nonconst to a const pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I'm studying the pointers, constness. I am confused at some point. I learned that assigning the address of const to a nonconst pointer is prohibited in C++ but it can be solved using const_cast. It's OK.

However, assigning the address of a nonconst variable to a const pointer is allowed. I didn't understand why it is allowed. Please look at the below example. In this example, ptr is a pointer to const int. However, the value which ptr points to changes. There is a contradiction here, because the const int value which ptr points to changes. Can you explain this contradiction, or if i am wrong, can you explain why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int year = 2012;
    const int* ptr = &year;
    year=100;
    year=101;
    cout << *ptr;
    // 101 is printed, the value ptr points to change whenever year changes

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `const int* ptr`, just mean can't change the value by `ptr`, you can't prevent other modification ways...

Comment: OMG, really?  then it means that it forbids onlymodification via dereferencing ptr

Comment: Yes, it  forbids only dereferencing ptr for writing. BTW: The const check is done at complile time, and as compiler, it's impossible to check other modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with file access, having a pointer-to-const is kind of like opening a file for read only. You are given a file handle that you can only use for reading, but that doesn't mean that the file can't be changed in some other way.

Similarly, when you have a pointer-to-const, you have a way of reading an object, but not writing. However, that doesn't mean the object can't be written to in some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example:

```
int year=5; // is allowed
//const int year=5;  // is also allowed

const int* ptr = &year;         // ptr points to const data, but has nonconst address
*ptr = 141;                     // its not allowed
++ptr;                          // allowed

int* const constPointer = &year; // ptr points to nonconst data, but has const adress
*constPointer = 8;              // allowed
++constPointer;                 // not allowed

// pointed value and pointer are const
const int* const constDataAndPointer = &year; // ptr points to const data, also has const adress
*constDataAndPointer = 124;     // not allowed
++constDataAndPointer;          // not allowed
```